# How to show loading icon in webview when we flip throug webviews in android

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

Actually my app hase 3 webviews and we can flip through it. I had added a loading progress bar on each webview. Now when i start the app, first web view loads. I am not able to flip the views as loading symbol is in foreground. My requirement is, webview have to show loading symbol until it loads as well as it can be flipped to other webviews which again have loading symbol.

I am tired of trying everything but not able to do it. Please anyone have any solution.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't do anyting when loading symol comes.we have to cancel it by back button for doing anything else. I had solved this by creating a progress bar in XML and doing a logic for making it visible and invisible according to requirement.